how to change the terminal prompt (bash) in vs code mac
so my terminal prompt in vs code mac is showing the process ID and then $. my current shell is bash. but i want my prompt to say the literal name of the directory that i am in and then a $ sign. if you guys can also tell how to set blue color for directory and gold color for $ sign then it would be great! thank you
i tried using nano and PS1 things but i think i'm doing it the wrong way. i want something like say i have a directory called hello i want my terminal to say hello/ $

To change the terminal prompt you should edit the PS1 variable.
Make sure you are using BASH in your VSCode terminal (with echo $0) and don't already have the variable PROMPT_COMMAND (with unset PROMPT_COMMAND).
              \w     the  value  of  the  PWD shell variable ($PWD), with $HOME
                     abbreviated  with  a  tilde  (uses  the   value   of   the
                     PROMPT_DIRTRIM variable)
              \W     the basename of $PWD, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
              \$     if the effective UID is 0, a #, otherwise a $

As you can see in BASH manual (section "PROMPTING"), if you want your command prompt to only show the current directory (not full path), you have 2 choices:

PS1='\w \$'; PROMPT_DIRTRIM=1 : this will display .../dir $ if your current directory is /etc/path/to/this/dir.
PS1='\W \$' : this will display dir $

Try these in your terminal, and once you're happy with the result store the PS1 variable definition (and PROMPT_DIRTRIM if wanted) in your ~/.bashrc file.
